# Getting duplicate Items from List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of model given below

```
string cellValue;
String cellAddress;
```

and sample values in this list are:

```
cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="A1";
cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="A2";
cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="A3";
cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="B1";
cellValue ="num" ; CellAddres="B2";
cellValue ="num" ; CellAddres="B3";
cellValue ="num1" ; CellAddres="B4";
cellValue ="txt1" ; CellAddres="C3";
```

what I want is to create lists of all duplicate values
like after processing  there should be two lists generated from this data

```
1)  cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="A1";
    cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="A2";
    cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="A3";
    cellValue ="txt" ; CellAddres="B1";
```

---

```
2)  cellValue ="num" ; CellAddres="B2";
    cellValue ="num" ; CellAddres="B3";
```

Comment: What about `cellValue="num1"` and `cellValue="txt1"` - why are they missing from your expected output?

Comment: I suppose - they did not repeat multiple times on the sample list so just skip them, and process only those repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, what you're trying to do is *group* your original list by `cellValue`. This will give you an `IGrouping<string,YourObject>`

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.cellValue);
```

This will give you 4 results (with `txt`,`num`,`txt1` & `num1` as the keys). Each grouping is an `IEnumerable<YourObject>` so you could enumerat each group as if it was its own list.

If you then wanted to exclude those groups which had only 1 child, you can use `Count()` inside a `Where`.

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.cellValue)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

This will now only have the 2 groups you specified as your required output.

Live example: http://rextester.com/RSN67321

Answer (score 1):

Is seems that you want `GroupBy()`, something like this:

```
List<MyItem> source = ...

var result = source
  .GroupBy(item => item.cellValue) 
  .Where(chunk => chunk.Count() > 1) // duplicates 
  .Select(chunk => String.Join("; ", chunk));
```